# How set a value between ...mapState (Vuex)

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-cli

In Vuex and View, how do you set a value or execute a function between `...mapActions(["getConfig"])`?

For example:

```js
methods: {
    this.theValue=true
    ...mapActions(["getConfig"])
    this.theValue=false
}
```

Comment: you can't execute arbitrary code inside an object literal declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing a response as a comment would be too short.

#### Wrapping the action

You need to call an action but also set up some value specific to your component. You need to wrap you action call such as

```js
{
  // ...
  methods:{
    ...mapActions(["getConfig"]),

    doGetConfig: async function(){
      this.theValue = true;
      await this.getConfig();
      this.theValue = false;
    }
  }
}
```

You have to assume as all actions are asynchronous hence the `async / await`.

#### `getConfig`

Un-related to your question but `getConfig` sounds a getter name. I wrote the answer above assuming that it would be something like `loadConfig`

Comment: @RipperNoChart, if this answer worked for you, please accept it to flag the question as completed. Otherwise, please let us know what is missing